# Tangents concurent at (1,1/2)

Tags: geometry

[image]

I got $y'=\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$..

after tht I got stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(s,t)=\left(s,\dfrac{s}{1+s^2}\right)$ is a point of tangency of the graph then the slope there is $m=\dfrac{1-s^2}{(1+s^2)^2}$ so the equation of the line of tangency is

$$ y-\dfrac{s}{1+s^2}= \dfrac{1-s^2}{(1+s^2)^2}(x-s)$$

In order for the line of tangency to contain the point $\left(1,\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ the following equation must be satisfied:

$$ \frac{1}{2}-\dfrac{s}{1+s^2}= \dfrac{1-s^2}{(1+s^2)^2}(1-s) $$

which simplifies to the polynomial equation

$$ s^4-4s^3+4s^2-1=0 $$

which factors

$$ (s-1)^2(s^2-2s-1)=0 $$

yielding the solutions $1\pm\sqrt{2}$ and the double solution $s=1$

So the points of tangency are

1. $\left(1,\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ with slope $m=0$
2. $\left(1+\sqrt{2},\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)$ with slope $m=1-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$
3. $\left(1-\sqrt{2},-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)$ with slope $m=1+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$

The three tangent lines have equations

1. $y=\dfrac{1}{2}$
2. $y=\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)x+\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}}{4}$
3. $y=\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)x+\dfrac{1-\sqrt{2}}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT 1: see picture below. Given curve is drawn in red.

[image]

HINT 2: if tangent line at $(x,y)$ passes through $\big(1,{1\over2}\big)$,
then 
$$
y'(x)={y-1/2\over x-1}.
$$